# Не выполняется полный запрос к БД

Tags: mysql, python, python-2.x, flask

Flask приложение, MySQL субд.
Он увеличивает счетчик id, но данные не подставляет из-за чего строк в таблице не прибавляется.

```
        file = request.files['img_data']
        text = request.form['text_data']
        title = request.form['text_title']
        filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
        cursor = mysql.connect().cursor()
        cursor.execute("SELECT MAX(id) FROM posts")
        filename = str(cursor.fetchone()[0]) + "." + get_ext(filename)
        file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
        cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO posts VALUE(NULL,"''' + title + "\",\"" + text + "\",\"" + filename + "\"," + '''NOW())''')
```

Соответственно в бд после запроса (второго, где insert) ничего нет, но если прописать вручную то такая штука (огромная разница между id, хотя строк всего три):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В общем не могу понять почему не вставляются данные.

Строка запроса: `INSERT INTO posts VALUE(NULL, "qwerty", "wertyui", "19.png", NOW())`. Данные по-прежнему не вставляются, даже после `mysql.connect().commit()`

Comment: Текст последнего запроса сперва соберите в переменной, и лишь потом отдавайте его в `cursor.execute()`. А тем временем покажите нам, что именно получилось в этой переменной.

Comment: Твою ж, даже тут умудряются делать SQL-инъекции на ровном месте! Кто вас научил так работать с mysql в питоне?

Comment: После insert, commit не нужен?

Comment: @andreymal так в том то и дело, что никто не учил...

Comment: Что ж, учитесь https://habrahabr.ru/post/321510/ Особенно раздел «Делаем подстановку значения в запрос»

Comment: @DmitryErohin похоже что он сохраняет данные, сейчас я попробую вывести данный запрос, а потом еще коммит.

Comment: @Akina вот запрос который вставляю в execute: INSERT INTO posts VALUE(NULL, "qwerty", "wertyui", "19.png", NOW())

Comment: Коммит нужно делать в том же самом соединении, в котором и курсор, а строчкой `mysql.connect()` вы похоже создаёте новое соединение

Comment: Запрос синтаксически неверен. Проверяйте, и не по словам, а ПО БУКВАМ.

Comment: @Akina запрос правильный. Проблема крылась в connect.commit().

Comment: @andreymal оформите как ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас, похоже, почему-то отключен автокоммит. При отключенном автокоммите все изменения нужно коммитить вручную через то же соединение, в котором изменения были внесены.

```
file = request.files['img_data']
text = request.form['text_data']
title = request.form['text_title']
filename = secure_filename(file.filename)

db_conn = mysql.connect()
cursor = db_conn.cursor()

cursor.execute("SELECT MAX(id) FROM posts")
filename = str(cursor.fetchone()[0]) + "." + get_ext(filename)
file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))

cursor.execute(
    'INSERT INTO posts VALUES (NULL, %s, %s, %s, NOW())',
    (title, text, filename),
)

db_conn.commit()
```

P.S. И не надо допускать SQL-инъекции тупым сложением строк при формировании  SQL-запроса